# /bypass folder on ArchBang - safe to delete?

Tags: arch-linux, root-filesystem, archbang

Anyone know what is this folder for, and if it's safe to delete it?

It's an ArchBang box, and this folder was there ever since install. I'm not really sure if it's just some junk left after installation, or if it genuinely has some purpose?

(edit: it's empty)

[image]

Comment: I guess it is not a system Directory, it is created by some user, so it is safe to delete it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Archbang project don't have a central code repository, so it is difficult to establish what the current state is, however, it appears that there is an option in the Archbang ISO to [bypass sections of the installer](https://github.com/mrgreen3/archbang/blob/master/root-image/usr/bin/abinstall#L19).

This directory [should have been removed](https://github.com/mrgreen3/archbang/blob/master/root-image/usr/bin/abinstall#L919) in the script but, for whatever reason, in your case it failed to do that.

You can remove the directory. If you want to be especially cautious, you can always rename it and then reboot before removing it, but it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Thanks, that'll be it. I'll remove it and hope that nothing breaks.